# Count unique values with condition (type, time)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

```
| monthly |Count (r.user_id)| Sum (p.price_amount)  |
|  15-01  |                 |                       |
|  15-02  |                 |                       |
|  15-03  |                 |                       |
|  15-04  |                 |                       |
|  15-05  |                 |                       |
```

I would like to write queries that ultimately would present like the above.

The closest format I could try to make a format to play with on excel was as below...

```
SELECT
r.user_id,
max(r.created_at) as "typeA_max",
min(r_a.created_at) as "TypeB_min",
max(r.created_at) - min(r_a.created_at) AS "interval"
FROM reservations r 
INNER JOIN offers o ON o.id = r.offer_id
INNER JOIN reservations r_a ON r_a.user_id = r.user_id AND o.type = 'A'
INNER JOIN payments AS p ON p.reservation_id = r.id
WHERe r.user_id in (
SELECT r.user_id
From reservations r
INNER JOIN offers o ON o.id = r.offer_id 
INNER JOIN reservations r_a ON r_a.user_id = r.user_id AND o.type = 'B'
Group by 1
Having count (r.id) >= 2
)
AND r.status = 'finish'
Group by 1
```

Throughout the rows, I've sampled and found a few mistakes though; Neither of the date of max(r.created_at) or min(r.created_at) were exclusively for each type like I thought I defined :(

I want to calculate:
- the number of unique users who purchased Type A before Type B at least a month ago. (i.e. Type B purchased on April 1st and Type A purchased on May 2nd -> count)

It would be whole lot easier if I could put
WHERE Max(r.created_at) - Min(r.created_at) > 30 
as filter but since that's not possible on WHERE clause (and I get constant errors when I apply "CASE WHEN" clause for this too) I don't know how to solve this problem.

Would really appreciate your help on this :)

Comment: I would like to suggest use nested query
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <table_name> WHERE ( your query ) as <table_name>

Comment: why not just put it on having? having (max(r.created_at)-min(r.created_at))>30